# How to append Dictionary keys null values in a list?

Tags: python, django, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has multiple keys and each key has multiple values in list format, if the keys have a `Null` value then the key should be `appended` to a list.

here is my dictionary:

```
{'XSTY':['21.01', '22.01'], 'STRY': ['31.01', None], 'SYER': ['34.21', None], 'HUHTY': [None, '45.22]}
```

and I am using this approach to append the value of the keys whose values are null in the list

```
final_dict = {'XSTY':['21.01', '22.01'], 'STRY': ['31.01', None], 'SYER': ['34.21', None], 'HUHTY': [None, '45.22]}
data = []
for in in final_dict.keys():
    if i == 'HUHTY':
        if len(final_dict[i]>0:
            data.append(i)
            print("Append Success")
        else:
            print("data did not append")
```

the above code is appending the data for this key only `HUHTY', but it should append the data for` STRY,SYER,HUHTY`all of these keys whose values are`None` inside the list. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

I know that it's not appending the other keys due to this condition `if i == 'HUHTY':`
please provide a better approach to do the same thing dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've indicated in the comments ("I have one more issue if I am passing this data variable in the email then it's sending me the same email 3 times. It's because it's looping 3 times") on the other answer that you want it in a string you can email, this will work:

```
final_dict = {'XSTY':['21.01', '22.01'], 'STRY': ['31.01', None], 'SYER': ['34.21', None], 'HUHTY': [None, '45.22']}
email_string = ', '.join([k for k,v in final_dict.items() if None in v])   

send_an_email(message=email_string) #for example, the print statements were for demonstration only
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
final_dict = {'XSTY':['21.01', '22.01'], 'STRY': ['31.01', None], 'SYER': ['34.21', None], 'HUHTY': [None, '45.22']}
data = [k for k,v in final_dict.items() for i in v if not i]    
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['STRY', 'SYER', 'HUHTY']
```

Comment: could you please modify the above code, it's displaying me the error in my code. When I am implementing the above code

Comment: Just use list comprehension for data instead of the for loop. Provided the whole code now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working as I expected.
I have one more issue if I am passing this data variable in the email then it's sending me the same email 3 times. It's because it's looping 3 times. 
is there any other approach where I can store the above data and then I can pass that variable in my email.

Comment: @sainitor use `join()` to make a string of the elements.

Comment: it's giving me the output like this....`['STRY']` and for next null value `['STRY', 'SYER']` and for next null value `['STRY', 'SYER', 'HUHTY']`, so it's sending the email 3 times. if there are more than 3 null values then it will send more than emails. but I want only the loop email where all the values are appending in the list. I want single email for this output `['STRY', 'SYER', 'HUHTY']`

Comment: Maybe run the email sending loop after generating the complete data list?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help you

```
datas ={'XSTY':['21.01', '22.01'], 'STRY': ['31.01', None], 'SYER': ['34.21', None], 'HUHTY': [None, '45.22']}
data = []
for k,v in datas.items():
  for z in v:
    if (z) ==None:
      data.append(k)
print(data)
```

Comment: it's working the same as the above code, it also sent the email 3 times when I am passing the `data` object in my email.

Comment: can you add your email  code?